# Visual Studio 2015 Подвисает

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Как исправить подвисания программы Visual Studio 2015?

Сначала не было глюков достаточно прошло много времени с установки почти год
и только недавно стало подвисать, сначала реже подвисала и сейчас начинаешь редактировать код стал чаще подвисать. (Я думаю что-то где-то забилось типа кеш)
Но я переставлял (исправлял) Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: если вы используете аддоны типа Resharper / Visual Assist ..., то следует почистить их базы символов. Сама студия создает папку .vs и SQLite (.db) базу данных для солюшна, их удаление может решить проблему

Comment: Вы точно уверены что это Студия, может это процессы которые она запускает?